# Web App and c++

Tags: c++, web-applications

It's something totally new for me, and since it seems to be something trivial, I can't find any response with our beloved friend ggle...
My question is : I have to create a webapp that can work if the client have nothing on his computer but a browser. My question is : is it possible to include to my project an external library (here I want to use PCL (Point Cloud library), a C++ library), and make it works even if the client have nothing installed? If I use QtWebKit for example, will I be able to create this kind of webapp?

Thanks a lot, and sorry for the (maybe) stupid question, I never did web dev before, it's my first time. ...

Have a nice day!

Comment: have a look at the google native code project - it allows running executables in a browser's sandbox

Comment: Basically, it's something that permit me to create a c++ application, and run it with google ? I assume it works only with chrome, is it possible on other browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that question is as broad as the day is long, but here goes (you don't give too much about your background so I apologise if I am going too basic).

A web browser is just a piece of software that knows how to process HTML, CSS and Javascript passed over HTTP from a TCP socket.

So, on a most basic level, to get something to work in a browser all you need is to write a program that listens on a TCP socket and passes headers and HTML in the body of the response as per the HTTP protocol.

So, leaving aside the socket part, your method may look something like this:

```
std::cout << "<h1>Hello, world!</h1>" << std::endl;
```

In fact, the vast majority of the original dynamic web sites worked just like this: they were just C programs that just happened to produce HTML as output in the old days (cgi-bin).

The main issue with this approach is it's very tedious and time consuming to write code to that level of detail to generate HTML, especially when you factor in CSS and JavaScript.

This is one of the key reasons that most web applications these days are implemented in Java, .Net, Ruby, PHP etc as there is a wealth of fully-featured, stable and mature frameworks for web development that take the grunt work out of creating dynamic web sites (and C/C++ is much rarer).

However there are a couple of good frameworks out there for C++ if that is definitely the language you want to use.

Wikipedia has a limited section on C++ frameworks but it covers the 2 I would suggest investigating (CppCMS and Wt):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_frameworks#C.2B.2B

Of these, I've only had direct experience of CppCMS but I can recommend it - it's approach is idiomatic C++ (to my eyes at least, but I must confess I am more often a Java web developer than C++)

Also, there is quite a useful if slightly dogmatic SO discussion on this thread that may be relevant:
[How popular is C++ for making websites/web applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417816/how-popular-is-c-for-making-websites-web-applications)

Comment: Wow! Thanks for this elaborate response. You're actually not going too basic since really my knowledge on this subject is null. I will check everything you linked.
At the actual time, I'm only in the brainstorming phase. So, since the C++ is my most well-known language, I was thinking about it. But what I want to achieve is basically a Point Cloud viewer/modificator in a WebApp, so i'm actually trying to find solutions. Maybe Java is a better solution, maybe .net, but I don't know if there is a way to work easily on Point Cloud using those language (I think yes, actually)

Comment: Two things to bear in mind: 
1) for intensive geometric work, C/C++ are generally favoured for their perceived performance benefits. 2) 3D visualisation in a web broswer is not trivial - despite protocols like VRML having been around for ages most solutions aer hand crafted

Comment: I have some ideas to reduce the 3D that will be used since operations I have to do are kinda easy (delete part of point cloud, select 2 points and calculate distance between, ...). Maybe I can create cubics from my position and make a correspondance in a Database with actual 3D point. I won't create something enormous in the browser, I don't want to frustrate the user with lags :). My real question is more if Webapp are standalone? If the user have nothing installed on his comp, will it works for him if he starts my app?

Comment: The short answer is yes, the user should be able to use any web app with just a web browser.  If you need any kind of complex dynamic functionality you will most likely need a Javascript application to run in their browser, but this would be downloaded from your web server like the HTML page, so no install required.